# The birth of Buddha

Tags: logic, ethics

Today my teacher said this during the classroom:

> Siddhartha Gautam, the earlier form of Buddha, was actually born in Nepal, but since Siddhartha Gautam meditated and found enlightenment to become Buddha while he was in India, many people mistakenly believe Buddha was born in India.

What I think is that those people who are saying Buddha was born in India is making a valid point. A person becomes Buddha only when he gets enlightenment and thus becomes entirely different from his previous state. That's why I think many people are making a valid point or a logical one.

But my teacher said that the body is just the same so no one cannot just say he was born in India as it is also against the morale of neighbouring country.

So I just want to get the clear picture of what is hapening here. Are people making the valid point? Is it misleading and against the morale?

Comment: I suspect the political geography of India/Nepal was different then; and possibly now quite hard to recover.

Comment: Buddha was born in what is now called Lumbini in modern Nepal. Lumbini is a few kms from the Indian border. I have been there. At the time of Buddha's birth there was no India and there was no Nepal. There were a number of small kingdoms in the region.

Comment: Swami Vishwananda　+1 you are probably correct. He was certainly referring to the name Nepal. I got his message wrongly. Sorry for that ( to the questioner )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a better fit for buddhism.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a better fit for history.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

People are using "Buddha" to mean two different things.

- The physical body of the guy identified as Buddha.
- The achievement of a mental state associated with that of a Buddha.

If they spent some time clarifying their terms, this argument would not arise.

The problem with natural language arguments is that often, people talk about different things, so it's a waste of time.  The greater part of such debates should be to clarify terms, and when that is done, often one realizes there was never any argument to begin with, just semantic confusion.

As for the moral of the story, whether it's irrelevant depends on how one treats Buddhism.  For those who take Buddhism to be a philosophy concerned with the relief of suffering, these details are irrelevant. For those who take Buddhism as a religion (and consider the person of the Buddha to be central), these details are of supreme importance.